# unpacking a tuple in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

Is there a way I can unpack a tuple in a tuple in Pyspark?
The data looks like this:

```
[('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', (26, 'X', 'A', '4724', '4724')), ('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', (21, 'S', 'A', '8247', '8247'))]
```

I want it to look like:

```
[('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', 26, 'X', 'A', '4724', '4724'), ('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', 21, 'S', 'A', '8247', '8247')]
```

Comment: Assuming they are all the same structure: `map(lambda x: x[:-1] + x[-1])`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks :) @AChampion

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen a list comprehension wouldn't really work in `Pyspark` - a cluster computing framework (distributed Map/Reduce).

Answer (score 3):

```
def unpack(record):
    unpacked_list = []
    for obj in record:
        if isinstance(obj, tuple):
            for obj_elem in obj:
                unpacked_list.append(obj_elem)
        else:
            unpacked_list.append(obj)
    return tuple(unpacked_list)

example_rdd = example_rdd.map(unpack)
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by AChampion in the comments, you can use `map(lambda x: x[:-1] + x[-1])` as follows:

```
data = sc.parallelize([
    ('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', (26, 'X', 'A', '4724', '4724')), 
    ('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', (21, 'S', 'A', '8247', '8247'))
])

data.map(lambda x: x[:-1] + x[-1]).collect()
```

This gives:

```
[('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', 26, 'X', 'A', '4724', '4724'),
 ('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', 21, 'S', 'A', '8247', '8247')]
```

Comment: Hard coding indices result in a function that is not easy to generalize

Comment: I would argue KISS here, there is no indication from the question this needs be generalised. Although your solution is more generic, I wanted to post this simpler implementation to complement your answer as it far easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
example = [('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', (26, 'X', 'A', '4724', '4724')), ('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', (21, 'S', 'A', '8247', '8247'))]
[tuple(x[:3]) + (x[3]) for x in example]
```

Result:

```
[('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', 26, 'X', 'A', '4724', '4724'), ('123', '0001-01-01', '2500-01-01', 21, 'S', 'A', '8247', '8247')]
```

Comment: Hard coding indices result in a function that is not easy to generalize.

Comment: @Jack_The_Ripper - I agree, maybe i trusted too much in the coding abilities of user by assuming he could wrap it into a function